# Создание новой базы данных Postgresql

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, база-данных, postgresql

Создаю тренировочные проекты на Django и использую БД Postgresql, собственно есть пара моментов где я запутался.
При создании нового проекта настройки БД у Django следущие:

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.postgresql',
        'NAME': 'mydatabase',
        'USER': 'mydatabaseuser',
        'PASSWORD': 'mypassword',
        'HOST': '127.0.0.1',
        'PORT': '5432',
    }
}
```

Для предыдущего проекта я создал нового юзера, новую базу данных, и задал пароль.
Вопросы:

1. Пароль который я задал, он для юзера, или для базы данных?
2. В новом проекте мне под тем же юзером нужно создать новую базу данных и просто поменять значение строки "NAME" ?
3. Как узнать какие базы данных были созданы у конкретного юзера?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> 1. Пароль который я задал, он для юзера, или для базы данных?

Для пользователя

> 2. В новом проекте мне под тем же юзером нужно создать новую базу данных и просто поменять значение строки "NAME" ?

Создать новую базу

> 3. Как узнать какие базы данных были созданы у конкретного юзера?

Список всех баз на сервере можно посмотреть через `psql` командой `\l` или запросом:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_database;
```

А список для конкретного пользователя можно получить запросом:

```
SELECT * FROM pg_catalog.pg_database
WHERE pg_catalog.pg_get_userbyid(datdba)='mydatabaseuser';
```